# Connecting to a Java server via Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a server on my PC that works fine. I've made small desktop app that connected to it flawlessly, but I can't get it to work on Android.

I've tried everything that I've found so far, changing ports, using 10.0.2.2 as the IP address, using PC IP address, making a new AVD and nothing has worked. My app is always crashing when making a new Socket.

This is my AsyncTask code:

```
public class ServerConnect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String serverIP = "10.0.2.2";
    Integer serverPort = 3000;
    Socket client;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            client = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),serverPort);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println("LOGIN "+ "test");
            Log.e("SOCKET", "Success");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SOCKET", "DERP");
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: `My app is always crashing ...` What does it mean, in practice? what does your logcat say?

Comment: `Log.e("SOCKET", "DERP");` you've done a good job shooting yourself in the foot by throwing away all the useful exception info. Now replace this line with something useful and edit your post with a full stack trace of the error. For example, `throw new RuntimeException(e)` would be oodles more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

As I can see from your code your code is wrapped in a try/catch meaning the crash isn't coming from your code.. meaning you probably don't have permissions for internet (in your case your inner network)